# How to change button background color in jquery mobile 1.4

Tags: jquery, css, mobile

On one of the posts I came across in the community, there was an example for glass button using gradient for jquery mobile 1.0.1.  I tried the same thing for 1.4 and it does not work.  Here is the code

```
<style>

    .ui-page .ui-content .ui-btn.my-btn .ui-btn-inner {
    color      : white;
    background : #f3c5bd; /* Old browsers */

    background : -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, 
    color-stop(0%,#A9BCF5), 
    color-stop(50%,#2E64FE), 
    color-stop(51%,#013ADF), 
    color-stop(75%,#2E64FE), 
    color-stop(100%,#0431B4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */

}
</style>
```

for html:

```
<button id="buttonCalculate" class="my-btn">Calculate</button>
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you want that CSS rule to apply to all of these different classes, you may want to separate the classes with commas. You will need a space and a comma between these two `.ui-btn.my-btn`.

Comment: Give same class name to button as the css has !

Comment: I worked fine for the 1.0.1 version.

Comment: there is no `.ui-btn-inner` in jQM 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use **my-btn** class for button , so you need to add it :

```
<style type="text/css">
    .my-btn {....}
</style>
```

Or :

```
#buttonCalculate{....}
```

Edit :

Add `!important` to every element because your styles are overrided.

Comment: You can use the id :  #buttonCalculate{...}

Comment: The button id works.  But it would be nice to have a class so I can apply to more than one button element.

Comment: I tried with my-btn as class="my-btn" and it totally ignored it.

Comment: i think your styles are overrided , try adding !important in the end of every style element.

Comment: Hey! You are right.  That seems to work.  You are super good.  You got my vote.